# NodeJS just hangs, no errors, no crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-server

Not sure if this is a JavaScript, Node.js or ParseServer specific issue.

I have the following CloudCode function (ParseServer):

```
Parse.Cloud.define('testingScores', function(request, response)
{
    var responseData = {"test_key1": "test_value1"};
    var query_scores = new Parse.Query("Score");

    query_scores.find({

                success: function(results) {
                    responseData.fromServer_scores = results;
                    response.success(responseData);
                },

                error: function(error) {
                    response.error("scores lookup failed");
                }
            });
});
```

This works fine as expected.
Now I change one of the lines to have a mistake as follows:

```
responseData.fromServer_scores = resultsss;
```

Obviously, `resultsss` is not defined anywhere. I know not to expect compile time errors with JavaScript, but at the very least there should be a runtime error. However when I run this, it just 'hangs'. Nothing in the console, no errors, simply the control does not continue past that line (if I put a console.log before and after the incorrect line, I only get the log before).

Why is this? Is there a way to make it throw a runtime error? Maybe some JavaScript/Node.js configuration?

Note:
If I wrap it in try-catch, I get the `'ReferenceError: resultsss is not defined'` in the console, but I can't try-catch every trivial line of code like this.

Note: I tried `"use strict";` with no luck.

Comment: There must be another try-catch higher up evilly swallowing the error.

Comment: Have you tried using Promises? You can try something like `query_scores.find().then(...successHandler...).catch(...errorHandler...)`. This way theoretically the catcher of the promise will also catch the `ReferenceError`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the answer I got from [Github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/297#issuecomment-227175460).

When dealing with Promises, it is considered a best practice to end the chain of .then() calls with a single .catch() to handle any exceptions that may have occurred in the chain.

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query("User");
userQuery.get("XhmDC123wh").then(function (user) {
    throw new Error('!');
}).catch(function(err) {
  // err === the error above
});
```